# free algebras and K-free algebras

Tags: universal-algebra

Given a set $X$ and a class $K$ of universal algebras of the same type $F$, an $F$-algebra $U$, generated by $X$, is said to be free over $X$ for the class $K$ if, for every $F$-algebra $A$ in $K$ and every function $\alpha\colon X\to A$ there exists exactly one $F$-morphism $\hat{\alpha}\colon U\to A$ extending $\alpha$. The problem here is that, in general, the free $F$-algebra over $X$ is not a member of $K$. To solve this problem, and conclude that, for instance, all varieties $V$ of algebras contain the $V$-free algebra over $X$, Burris-Sankappanavar [in their Universal Algebra textbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html) at page 73, introduce this construction:

Take the term algebra $T(X)$ of $F$-terms over a set $X$, take the smallest congruence $\theta$ on $T(X)$ to which corresponds a quotient $T(X)/\theta\in IS(K)$ (the class of algebras isomorphic to a subalgebra of a member of K), then $T(X)/\theta$ is in $K$ when, for instance, $K$ is a variety (a class of algebras closed under subalgebras, homomorphic images and direct products of its members). More precisely, let
$$\theta_K(X):=\bigcap\Phi_K(X)$$
and
$$\Phi_K(X):=\{\theta\in Cong(T(X)): T(X)/\theta\in IS(K)\}$$
Then define the $K$-free algebra over $X$ as:
$$F_K(X):=T(X)/\theta_K(X)$$

My question is: how do we know, in general, that $\Phi_K(X)$ is non-empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it could be empty. This is the case for example if $K$ is empty, because in that case $IS(K)$ is empty, so there is no congruence such that $T(X)/\theta\in IS(K)$.

But if you look at the remarks after Definition 10.9, it says :

> (4) If $K=\emptyset$ or $K$ consists only of trivial algebras, then $F_K(\overline{X})$ is a trivial algebra as $\theta_K(X)=\nabla$.

In fact, $\theta_K(X)$ should be defined as the *infimum* (or meet) of the set $\Phi_K(X)$ in the lattice of congruences of $T(X)$. If $\Phi_K(X)$ is non-empty, then this infimum is the intersection of all the congruences in $\Phi_K(X)$, but if is empty then its infimum is simply the largest congruence $\nabla$.

Comment: What happens if $K$ is empty and $F_K(\bar{X})$ is trivial (just one element)?

Comment: If $K$ is empty, then $IS(K)$ is empty, hence $\Phi_K(X)$ is empty as well, and thus $\theta_K(X)=\nabla$. Note that in that case any algebra is (vacuously) free over $X$ for $K$.